# Will Kafka Producer always waits for the value specified by linger.ms, before sending a request?

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

As per LINGER_MS_DOC in ProducerConfig java class:

> "The producer groups together any records that arrive in between
> request transmissions into a single batched request. Normally this
> occurs only under load when records arrive faster than they can be
> sent out. However in some circumstances the client may want to reduce
> the number of requests even under moderate load. This setting
> accomplishes this by adding a small amount of artificial delay; that
> is, rather than immediately sending out a record the producer will
> wait for up to the given delay to allow other records to be sent so
> that the sends can be batched together. This can be thought of as
> analogous to Nagle's algorithm in TCP. This setting gives the upper
> bound on the delay for batching: once we get "BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG" worth
> of records for a partition it will be sent immediately regardless of
> this setting, however if we have fewer than this many bytes
> accumulated for this partition we will 'linger' for the specified time
> waiting for more records to show up. This setting defaults to 0 (i.e.
> no delay). Setting "LINGER_MS_CONFIG=5" for example, would have the
> effect of reducing the number of requests sent but would add up to 5ms
> of latency to records sent in the absence of load."

I searched for a suggested value for linger.ms but nowhere found a higher value suggested for this. Most of the places 5 ms is mentioned for linger.ms.

For testing, I have set "batch.size" to 16384 (16 KB)
and "linger.ms"  to 60000 (60 seconds)
as per doc I felt if I send a message of size > 16384 bytes then the producer will not wait and send the message immediately, but I am not observing the same behavior.

I am sending events of size > 16384 bytes but it still waits for 60 seconds. Am I missing to understand the purpose of "batch.size"? My understanding of "batch.size" and "linger.ms" is that whichever meets first the messages/batch will be sent.

In this case, if it is going to be the minimum wait time and do not give preference to "batch.size" then I guess setting a high value for linger.ms is not right.

Here is the kafka properties used in yaml:

```
  producer:
    properties:
      acks: all
      retries: 5
      batch:
        size: 16384
      linger:
        ms: 10
      max:
        request:
          size: 1046528
```

Comment: Are you applying any compression that might reduce the message size?

Comment: No compression is applied.

Comment: Is ot possible to share a minimal reproducable example?

Comment: I have added the YAML config used for kafka producer. Till now I observed that producer never waits more than linger.ms time and it never sends a request if total message size is less than batch.size and elapsed time is also less than linger.ms. The basic question is can Kafka producer sends a request if batch.size is achieved but elapsed time is less than linger.ms?